# Выделение содержимого TextCtrl при получении фокуса

Tags: python, wxpython, выделение-текста

## Вариант 1.

```
import wx

class wndSelect(wx.Dialog):
    def __init__(self):
        """Constructor"""

        wx.Dialog.__init__(self, None, title="Выделение текста",size=(160,130))
        self.Centre()

        self.aaa=wx.TextCtrl(self, id=1, value='Текст 1', size=(120, 30), pos=(10, 10))
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_SET_FOCUS, self.SelectText, self.aaa)

        self.bbb=wx.TextCtrl(self, id=2, value='Текст 2', size=(120, 30), pos=(10, 50))
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_SET_FOCUS, self.SelectText, self.bbb)


    def SelectText(self, event):
        idTc=event.GetId()
        if idTc==1:
            self.aaa.SetFocus()
            self.aaa.SetSelection(-1,-1)
            print('1')
        elif idT==2:
            self.bbb.SetFocus()
            self.bbb.SetSelection(-1,-1)
            print('2')

        event.Skip()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = wx.App(False)
    frmSelect = wndSelect()
    frmSelect.ShowModal()
```

## Вариант 2

```
import wx

class wndSelect(wx.Dialog):
    def __init__(self):
        """Constructor"""

        wx.Dialog.__init__(self, None, title="Выделение текста",size=(160,130))
        self.Centre()

        self.aaa=wx.TextCtrl(self, id=1, value='Текст 1', size=(120, 30), pos=(10, 10))
        self.aaa.Bind(wx.EVT_SET_FOCUS, self.SelectText)

        self.bbb=wx.TextCtrl(self, id=2, value='Текст 2', size=(120, 30), pos=(10, 50))
        self.bbb.Bind(wx.EVT_SET_FOCUS, self.SelectText)


    def SelectText(self, event):
        idTc=event.GetId()
        event.EventObject.SetFocus()
        event.EventObject.SetSelection(-1,-1)

        event.Skip()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = wx.App(False)
    frmSelect = wndSelect()
    frmSelect.ShowModal()
```

Непонятно, почему не срабатывает выделение.
Когда назначаешь С ПОМОЩЬЮ ДОПОЛНИТЕЛЬНОЙ КНОПКИ фокус элементу и выделение его содержимого,
все срабатывает. Но не делать же каждому текстовому полю отдельную кнопку для выделения.
Конечно, можно при попадании в элемент очищать его содержимое, но это нарушает "философию программы".
В общем, хотелось бы понять суть проблемы.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Выделять содержимое нужно после установки фокуса. Для этого нужно вызвать `SetSelection` после обработки всех событий установки фокуса с помощью `wx.CallAfter`.

```
def SelectText(self, event):
    wx.CallAfter(event.EventObject.SetSelection, -1, -1)
    event.Skip()
```

В вашем случае не нужно вызывать `SetFocus`, если вы вызываете `event.Skip()`. `Skip()` приводит к вызову следующего в очереди обработчика события. Так как у вас всего одна привязка события к `wx.EVT_SET_FOCUS`, то `event.Skip()` приведет к вызову базового обработчика, который установит фокус.

Вместо `wx.TextCtrl.SetSelection` можно использовать `wx.TextCtrl.SelectAll`. Тогда получим следующую функцию:

```
def SelectText(self, event):
    wx.CallAfter(event.EventObject.SelectAll)
    event.Skip()
```